# Recalcular columna en datatable al ordenar por cualquier columna Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatable, ordenar

hola estoy intentando recalcular la culumna de balance de una datatable al ordenarlo por cualquier columna que desee el usuario. El calculo de la columna de balance es DB - CR. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aqui muestro mi tabla inicial ordenado por fecha y la columna de balance se calcula bien.

Como seria la mejor forma de recalcular la columna sin consultar los datos a la base de datos nuevamente. aqui mi codigo de carga de datos.

```js
    t = $('#ListaMovi').DataTable();
    t.clear().draw();     
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url:BuscaListaMovi,          
      beforeSend: function () {
      },
      success:  function (response) {        
        var DB = 0 ;
        var CR = 0 ;
        var Balance = 0;
        obj = JSON.parse(response);          
        $.each(obj.ListaMovi, function( i, Deta ) { 
        DB += parseFloat(Deta.DB) ;          
        CR += parseFloat(Deta.CR) ;          
        Balance += (parseFloat(Deta.DB) - parseFloat(Deta.CR));
            t.row.add( [                    
                Deta.Fecha ,
                Deta.TipoCargo,                                                  
                Deta.NoDoc,                                                  
                Deta.NoCK,
                Deta.Concepto,
                accounting.formatNumber(Deta.DB,2),
                accounting.formatNumber(Deta.CR,2),
                accounting.formatNumber(Balance,2)                 
            ] ).draw( false ); 
        });
```

Comment: No entiendo si queres ordenar o recalcular tu datatable con alguna info nueva que ingresaron.

Comment: recalcular la misma tabla, al ordenar por alguna columna diferente a la default el orden de la columna balance cambia.